# "invalid ORDER BY expression" with HSQLDB and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I am accessing an embedded HSQLDB 2.3.2 database using Hibernate 4.1.7

Here is my HQL query

```
FROM RunE x  ORDER BY x.startedAt
```

And here is the SQL being generated by Hibernate which is shown on the console as a result of configuring **hibernate.show_sql** to **true**

```
select
    rune0_.ID as ID6_,
    rune0_.FINISHED_AT as FINISHED2_6_,
    rune0_.PERCENT_COMPLETE as PERCENT3_6_,
    rune0_.PROBLEM as PROBLEM6_,
    rune0_.PROC_PARAMS as PROC7_6_,
    rune0_.PROCESSOR as PROCESSOR6_,
    rune0_.RUN_TYPE as RUN4_6_,
    rune0_.STARTED_AT as STARTED5_6_
from
    ZA_RUN rune0_
order by
    rune0_.STARTED_AT
```

The final cause exception comes from HSQLDB and is:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid ORDER BY expression
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveColumnRefernecesInOrderBy(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveColumnReferences(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveReferences(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
```

According to the [HSQLDB manual](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html) the syntax of the query looks fine. I also tried it with [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) with the same hsqldb-2.3.2.jar library in which it compiles and runs, but it fails when using Hibernate.

As a further test I removed the `ORDER BY x.startedAt` from my HQL resulting in the SQL

```
select
    rune0_.ID as ID6_,
    ...
    rune0_.STARTED_AT as STARTED5_6_
from
    ZA_RUN rune0_
```

and it ran fine, so it does seem to be related to the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Enable SQL logging in HSQLDB and see if the actual SQL statement is the same.